# Ubuntu 14.10 black screen at login

Tags: screen, login-screen

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.10 on my laptop Compaq 420, just a while ago. At login screen, it suddenly becomes black for a split second and then shows it again. Or sometimes, it appears after you typed your username and password then shows the desktop. It also appears when you logout, this time a couple of times before showing the login screen. Is this something to do with the login manager ? I find this annoying so any help would be really appreciated.

Memory: 3.8 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T6670 @ 2.20GHz × 2
Graphics: Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset
OS type: 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Once you are booted up to the blank desktop... press CTRL + ALT + F1.

```
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install unity
apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee*
apt-get install nvidia-prime

shutdown -r now
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not that I have a blank desktop, it still shows. And I have an intel video card, do i really need to install nvidia drivers ? Thanks.

Comment: steps is to purge the driver and to reinstall...you can still reinstall your intel driver to check this.

Comment: The problem still persist. Do you have another workaround ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the terminal (CTRL+ALT+F1) and then remove the configuration file ~/.config/dconf/user like this :

(this action will remove your gnome 3 settings)

```
sudo service lightdm stop
rm ~/.config/dconf/user
sudo service lightdm start

shutdown -r now
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't work either but thanks for your help.